# Navigation is delayed when keyboard is on screen - Swift 4 - Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, navigation

Is it possible that iOS have a little bug caused by the system keyboard?

I'll explain myself:

Navigation between views is fast as long as you don't load hard stuff in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear, even in old devices.

BUT, there are two conditions where I'm getting an annoying delay:

1. When I show a keyboard in viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear (becomeFirstResponder)
2. When keyboard is in screen, and I pop the view.

It seems that while keyboard is showing/hiding, the navigation is frozen, because the delay is about the time of the keyboard's hide/show animation.

I tried endEditing(force: true), and resignFirstResponder in viewWillDisappear (when I pop a view), but didn't work.

I have an iPhone 6s, and I noticed that Whatsapp and Twitter have the same problem.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
The App Store has the same problem...
Notice the delay when the back button is pressed with keyboard on screen...

**Without keyboard:**

[image]

**With keyboard:**

[image]

Comment: are you getting notifications about keyboard showing/hiding and reacting to it?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Yes, but I tried removing it (commenting the notification subscription line)

Comment: I had a similar (though not the same) problem just yesterday, and all I needed to do was to disable animating the layout along the keyboard.. so I could still adapt to keyboard showing, but without trying to animate along with it.. and it solved my problem - in my case I wasn't getting called my panGestureRecognizer during keyboard showing.. when I removed `UIView.animate`, I got it working (`UIView.animate` disables user interaction, so it would seem)

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Can you specify a little, please? What did you do exactly? I tried to disable animations when I hide the keyboard, but that only removes the animation, keeping the delay time. I noticed the App Store has the same problem (with search keyboard), so it's worrying...

Comment: I was using `UIView.animate` to adapt to keyboard change. removing this animation solved my problem. but I wasn't presenting/dismissing view controllers.. maybe try to implement and share a minimal working example that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I edited de post, uploading two gifs to show de delay (I forgot to change sencond gif link name...)

Comment: @MilanNosáľ you can reproduce this delay, just creating two view controllers in one navigation controller, putting a button in the first one in order to navigate to the second VC, and showing keyboard in the second one (in viewDidLoad).